# Do I need an app.yaml for my App Engine project?

Tags: google-app-engine

I keep reading in App Engine references about configuration directives that go into app.yaml, such as 'DBG_ENABLE'. But I can't find this file in my Android Studio created GAE project. Furthermore, I find that some of the directives in this file (for instance: Scaling) also have equivalent in appengine-web.xml.

So, what's the deal with this yaml file - do I need to create it? Where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no app.yaml file created by Android studio, because usually you use Java Serverlet to implement the App Engine Application under Android Studio, it uses the /WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml file to configure the project.

The app.yaml file is used for the App Engine Project using Python, Go and PHP.